# With arquillian incontainer mode ,Why Test method is getting exeduted square of the times of values returned by data provider in testng?

Tags: testing, testng, jboss-arquillian

I'm using TestNG as Unit Test Framework and  Jboss AS7.1.1 Final as server

The data provider  and Test methods works well in Client Mode

The same dataprovider will return 10 rows and my Test method is getting executed nearly 100times in In container mode

**Test method**

```
   @Test(groups="bean-tests",dataProvider="Presenter-Data-Provider")

   public void findByIdPositiveTest(long presenterId,String expectedPresenterName)

   {



   }
```

**Dataprovider method:**

```
@DataProvider(name = "Presenter-Data-Provider")

public  Object[][] presenterTestDataProvider()

{



    EntityManagerFactory emf=null;

    EntityManager em=null;

    Object testcaseData[][]=null;

    Session session=null;

    try

    {

        emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestCaseDataSource");

        em=emf.createEntityManager();

        session=em.unwrap(Session.class);

        Criteria query=session.createCriteria(TestPresenter.class).setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(10);

        List<TestPresenter> rowList=query.list();

        testcaseData=new Object[rowList.size()][2];

        for(int loopCount=0;loopCount<rowList.size();loopCount++)

        {

            TestPresenter row=rowList.get(loopCount);



            testcaseData[loopCount][0]=row.getPresenterId();

            testcaseData[loopCount][1]=row.getExpectedPresenterName();

        }





    }

    catch(Exception exception)

    {

      mLog.error(exception.getMessage()); 

    }

    return testcaseData;



}
```

I'm running as Test Suite using folowing Suite configuration

```
<test name="Bean testing">

    <groups>

        <run>

            <!-- This has to be added by default while using arquillian Test Runner -->

            <include name="arquillian" />

            <include name="bean-tests" />



        </run>

    </groups>

    <classes>

        <class name="blah.blah.blah.PresenterManagerBeanTest" />

    </classes>

</test>
```

Pls let me know What I did was wrong
 Or direct me how to get values from DB  to Data provider and tests using In container mode

Thanks in advance

sathiya seelan

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's related to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-1282. Issue is still open.